# Distribution of median of three exponential observations

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

I just had a question in my exam that I couldn't answer, I bugged.

You're given $X = \text{Median}(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3).$

$X$ follows an exponential distribution and you're asked to find the pdf of $X.$ My attempt was to find the cdf then derive.

Can someone explain me how I should have resolved it and what is the intuition behind the resolution.

Thanks you !

Comment: Look at 'order statistics', Standard discussion: There is a formula for the PDF of the $i$th order statistic in terms of CDF and PDF of the population distribution. Should be tractable to find PDF of your median (2nd order statistic) $Y_{(2)}$ because exponential CDF and PDF are so simple.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment continued** (not Answer). From the standard exponential distribution
(rate and mean both unity), I took a million samples of size $n = 3$ and
found the median $h$ of each. Here is a histogram of the results. When
you get your PDF you can compare it with the histogram. For a start, the
distribution of $h$ is clearly not exponential. [The red curve is the PDF
I got following the hints in my (real) Comment.]

[image]

*Note:* In case the formula for the PDF of the $i$th order statistic is not
in your text or notes, look [*here* at 7th slide](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Lectures/Lec15.pdf) or about halfway down the Wikipedia article on 'order statistics'.