# Distribution of median of three unordered independent exponential observations

Tags: statistics

Related post: [Distribution of median of three exponential observations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660836/distribution-of-median-of-three-exponential-observations)

However, Suppose $Y=Median(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ where $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are unordered, i.e. $X_1>X_2$ or $X_1<X_2$ are all possible, independent exponential distribution with paramater $\theta$.

What's the pdf for $Y$?

Comment: Are you saying that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are all independently distributed? If that is the case, something like $X_1>X_2$ (which is ordered) is not possible as there is a clear dependency between the variables.

Comment: $S_3$ acts on $(\mathbb{R}^+)^3$ measure-preservingly, so order doesn't matter.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Right, $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are all independently distributed. But I was thinking we can separate them into cases like $X_1\geq X_2\geq X_3$,$X_1\leq X_2 \leq X_3$ and then substruct the terms like $X_1=X_2=X_3$ and $X_1=X_3$ that was double counted. But I don't seem to get the answer.